# How to emulate mouse scroll in openbox?

Tags: ubuntu, scrolling, emulation, openbox

I use laptop a lot and have no mouse.
I use trackpoint which substitutes the mouse very well except scrolling.
Is it possible to bind scrolling of windows to - for example - '<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + middle + mouse?

I was using Ubuntu recently and found out that such feature is there. I mean if middle button is pressed then mouse moving scrolls windows content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After longer research it turned out that it's matter of Xorg (instead of openbox as i thought initially).

I found 2 solutions:

1. Get zip from link (it's compressed dir from ubuntu with the feature):

   http://speedy.sh/jfpqM/emulate-scroll.zip

   Create backup of Your system dir:

   ```
   $ sudo cp -r /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d-bck
   ```

   Replace dir *"/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/"* with the one from zip. That's it.
2. get the dedicated program for that.. more info at links:

   https://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings

   **www.grepmonster.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/ubuntu-11-10-middle-mouse-button-emulation/** (this is not link, because i'm too new to include 3 links in one post, sorry :) )